# How to convert the palette offset bytes to an image?

Tags: python, image, reverse-engineering, palette

So, there I have a .ppz file, which contains offsets in palette array. Exactly this file contains 51 images. The first two bytes are the offset to the header. The header stores the width, height, image size and data size (size of the offsets bytes). And then there are the offsets themselves in the palette array. Each bit is one color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnCTw.png)

This file was obtained after unpacking another file in which the colors used in these images were stored in the header.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdT5C.png)

Is there a way to convert palette offsets to 24 bit BMP or RAW 24? Preferably in python.

Comment: You have a `.ppz` file? What is it please? Where does it come from? Please share it (Dropbox or Google Drive). You unpacked another file? Ok, where is that please? Where is the description of that? Who/what created it? You want to create a BMP - how can you do that if you only have palettes and no indexes into the palettes? Please try to improve your question. Thank you.

Comment: There is an old game in which resources are stored in the following formats: pictures - pzx, pzd; frames - pzf; animation - pza. The header of the pzx file contains information: how many images are packed, the bytes of colors that are contained in the images, the size before and after decompression. I unpacked the PZX file using zlib into PPZ format. I described what the PPZ-file contains at the beginning of my question. I would like to convert the offsets in the palette array to actual images.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hxZb41yT0eoRvx4uRYrMW9sLkzxYX8Vp?usp=sharing